# casting delegate using errorbox returns fault

Tags: c#

Im completely stumped on where to go from here.

heres my line of code that i cant get past.

```
  if (error.GetReaction(ErrorReaction.InformUser) == null)
                {
                    error.SetReaction(new ErrorReactionClass(ErrorReaction.InformUser, (CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 != null) ? CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 : (CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = new Method(ErrorMessageBox.ShowDialog)), "OK", ""));
                }
```

i get the following errors from this

Error   30  'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()' has the wrong return type
Error   31  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()'

Comment: We're going to need more information.  Definitely include the function signatures and delegate type declaration.

Comment: Why are you trying to compile such code?

Comment: He must have one of those giant 30" monitors, I'm jealous.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors here.

1. The call to ShowDialog doesn't have the return type your delegate is expecting.
2. You can't call "ShowDialog" on a type, since it's not a static method.  You need to provide an actual instance.

I suspect that this may do what you need:

```
// Not sure how many arguments your "Method" delegate gets
Method showDialog = (arg1, arg2) =>
{
     var form = new ErrorMessageBox();
     // Setup form with arg1/arg2/etc
     form.ShowDialog();

     // return appropriate return type here...
};

error.SetReaction(
    new ErrorReactionClass(
        ErrorReaction.InformUser, 
        (CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 != null) 
            ? CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 
            : (CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = showDialog)
        , "OK", ""));
```